# Ng-select inside dialog add extra hidden height

Tags: angular

when using ng-select inside a dialog, the content of the dropdown is not displayed outside the dialog with an overflow. I saw this question also on github, but there was no solution found.

https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/240

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-yesgfz

How can I solve this?

Expected behaviour:

[image]

Actual behaviour:

[image]

Solution from github with [appendTo]="'body'"

[image]

Comment: Does the solution `[appendTo]="'body'"` don't work as stated on the github ticket?

Comment: I Edited the question with what it looks like with [appendTo]="'body'"

Comment: Looks like It was able to get out of the dialog, can try updating it's `z-index` to a much higher value than the dialog?

Comment: I will +1 this question because `[appendTo]="'body'"` did work for me. I have a `ng-select` element inside a component that sits inside a `mat-expansion-panel`, and the contents at the bottom would get cut off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, even if it's probably not ideal, do this

```
<div style="display: block; height: 40px;">
  <ng-select [searchable]="false" style="position: absolute; width: 200px;">
    <ng-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
      {{ option }}
    </ng-option>
  </ng-select>
</div>
```

Requires some fixed values, but the absolute position solves your issue and fiddling a bit with css may give you the result you want in a decent way.

Edit: [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-qo7wgi)

Comment: Works perfect for my purpose. Thanks

Comment: Position="absolute" does not work in IE. Any change on how to get it to work in IE?

Comment: Comments state that you have to set a relative position to the absolut positioned elements parent, but don't know if that works here. But pretty sure that there are many solutions on the web and feel free to edit the post then.

Answer (score 14):

paste appendTo="body" on your ng-select tag

`<ng-select appendTo="body" [items]="data" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id" placeholder=""></ng-select>`

Answer (score 0):

For posterity:
It seems the selectors have shifted somewhat. The previous class names have migrated to attributes and now the css reads as

```
.custom-dialog-container {
  .mat-mdc-dialog-content,
  .mat-mdc-dialog-surface {
    overflow: visible;
  }
}
```